# Create TeamCity project from local TortoiseSVN repository

Tags: svn, teamcity

I am new to both frameworks (TortoiseSVN and TeamCity). I would like to play around with a small repository I have made using TortoiseSVN in the following path `D:\TEMP\FortranTest\ifort\MyRepo`.

Following the instructions in [this link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configure+and+Run+Your+First+Build#ConfigureandRunYourFirstBuild-CreateaprojectpointingtorepositoryURL) I would like to create a TeamCity project that uses a local repository as its project repository. To get into TeamCity I typed `localhost` into my browser and logged in. Then under create project>repository URL I tried two things:

```
D:/TEMP/FortranTest/ifort/MyRepo
svn://D:/TEMP/FortranTest/ifort/MyRepo
```

The first gave me this error

> Cannot create a project using the specified URL. The URL is not
>   recognized.

The second gave me another error

> Error connecting the specified URL: svn: E210003: Unknown host d

How do I add a local repository URL created by TortoiseSVN to my TeamCity project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this worked for me using a Maven-like link:

```
scm:svn:file://localhost/path_to_repository
```